# Webview flutter android compatibilit minSDK issue

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I'm new in Flutter, I am developing a mobile application using flutter_html package. The application encountering an error below

```
"..\build\webview_flutter_android\intermediates\library_manifest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 16
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 19,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="io.flutter.plugins.webviewflutter" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)"
```

I tried to change the minSdk to 16 as suggested to this file`\build\webview_flutter_android\intermediates\library_manifest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml`. But still encountering an error. Any help please.

Comment: Try setting project `minSDK` version to 24

Comment: This question has an answer here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/74245028/6921031

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please add minSdkVersion 21 in app/build.gradle file. it works good.