# Change Android minSDk Version Flutter New SDK

Tags: flutter

I need to change SDK version on Android but now on build.gradle (in root/android/app/build.gradle) looks like

```
defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.bla.bla"
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion  // here is the cause
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
```

I know I can replace with **flutter.minSdkVersion** to **version code** manually (I tried, It works). But I need to know the best way...

Update:
I'm Using Flutter 2.8.1 • channel stable & Dart 2.15.1

Comment: refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52060516/how-to-change-android-minsdkversion-in-flutter-project)

Comment: @gretal
I know I can replace with flutter.minSdkVersion to version code manually (I tried, It works). But I need to know the best way...

Comment: I think that can be done only manually.

Comment: check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52060516/how-to-change-android-minsdkversion-in-flutter-project/70316521#70316521

Comment: Are you asking if it's possible to redefine flutter.minSdkVersion itself?   I don't think it is.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Math.max`:

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.bla.bla"
        minSdkVersion Math.max(flutter.minSdkVersion, 19)  // here is the change
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
```

But personally I would just use the specific version number.

Answer (score 0):

With the new Flutter projects (2.8.0), with the 'Flutter style', you able to change minimum sdk version in local.properties (instead of editing app/build.gradle file).

```
# android/local.properties

flutter.minSdkVersion=19
Look in android/app/build.gradle file, you'll see the variable
```

constraint like this:

```
# android/app/build.gradle

android {

  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly change the min SDK version in build.gradle file

```
defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "com.bla.bla"
    minSdkVersion 'You can set version // for ex.16'  
    targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
}
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the above methods is working or is reliable.

Please follow the steps below to fix this issue:

Step 1. Locate the Flutter SDK on your device.
Step 2. Locate the packages folder inside.

[image]

Step 3. Go inside packages -> flutter-tools -> gradle -> flutter

[image]

Step 4. Double-click the flutter folder and open it in notepad to edit.

Step 5. Edit the required min SDK variable inside and save the file.

[image]

Step 6. Rerun the app and you will find no error now.

Thanks :)